# What is the set of solutions to $2\log_{\cos x}\sin x\le \log_{\sin x}\cot x$ where $0<x<\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, logarithms, quadratics

> $$2\log_{\cos x}\sin x\le \log_{\sin x}\cot x$$ where $0<x<\pi$

My process:

Since both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ must be greater than $0$ and less than $1$, the initial set shrinks to $(0,\pi/2)$

Then after transformations I get

$2\log_{\cos x}\sin x+1-\log_{\sin x}\cos x\le 0$

.
.
.

$2t^2+t-1\le 0$

. . .

$\log_{\cos x}\sin x\in [-1,1/2] $

Can't be $[-1,0)$

But I'm not sure what the interval is further

I'd venture a guess as to say that $x\in (0,\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}]$ but that doesn't fit with the solution on the exam, which doesn't explicitly give the solution but says it is in the form of $(a,b)$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Few typos here, what is $ctgx$? Also, you trig and log functions require a backslash.

Comment: I changed “ctg” to the more common (internationally) “cot” (cotangent).

Comment: Someone beat me to it :)

Comment: @JohnDoe right! Not aware of that, perhaps it's more used across the pond. Thanks for edit. Actually, your question is a very good one!

Comment: Do you mean $0<x<\pi/2$? Otherwise you have 1) negative base and 2) negative argument to your logarithm. How are they supposed to be defined?

Comment: It's just how the original problem was formulated, I did restrict $x$ to that domain immediately and mentioned it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $\displaystyle 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Note that $\ln\cos x<0$ and $\ln \sin x<0$.

\begin{align}
\frac{2\ln \sin x}{\ln \cos x}&\le\frac{\ln \cos x-\ln\sin x}{\ln\sin x}\\
2(\ln\sin x)^2&\le(\ln\cos x)^2-\ln\sin x\ln \cos x\\
(\ln\cos x)^2-\ln\sin x\ln \cos x-2(\ln\sin x)^2&\ge0\\
(\ln \cos x+\ln \sin x)(\ln\cos x-2\ln \sin x)&\ge0\\
\ln\cos x-2\ln\sin x&\le0\\
\ln\cos x&\le\ln\sin^2x\\
\cos x&\le1-\cos^2x\\
\left(\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2&\le\frac{5}{4}\\
0<\cos x&\le\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\le x&<\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: It seems this indeed is the answer. I guess the solution on the test must be wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

The first restriction to $0<x<\pi/2$ is correct.

Note now that
$$
\log_ab=\frac{1}{\log_ba}
$$
so if you set $t=\log_{\sin x}\cos x$ you get
$$
\frac{2}{t}+1-t\le0
$$
that is
$$
\frac{t^2-t-2}{t}\ge0
$$
The solution set of this is
$$
[-1,0)\cup[2,\infty]
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I don't see a case where $t$ may be smaller than $0$ so when I set the other logarithm to $t$, I just multiplied by $t$. That said, I still don't see how my or your interval fits in the end into a nice $(a,b)$ interval.

Comment: @JohnDoe So you just have $\log_{\sin x}\cos x\ge2$, which means $\cos x\le \sin^2x$.

Comment: Thanks, I did get in the ballpark of that, but the test solution says the interval is strictly exclusive, which made me think there was more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite this equation using the [change of base formula](http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm):

$$\log_a(b) = \frac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}$$ for any value of $c$.

Here, we can say that $c=e$, i.e. we are using the natural logarithm:

\begin{align}2\log_{\cos x}\sin x&\leq \log_{\sin x}\cot x\\\\
\frac{2\ln(\sin x))}{\ln(\cos(x))}&\leq \frac{\ln(\cot(x))}{\ln(\sin(x))}\end{align}

Can you now solve this?

Comment: I did do this in my attempt to solve the problem, but with a different base. I don't see why I would get an another answer with this approach. That is, I don't know how to continue with what I've got (assuming it's true)

Comment: @JohnDoe [CY Aries' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2313338/401264) finishes off this approach